# Android App development using xamarin

Tags: android

I am using Visual studio 2015 + Xamarin ( C# ) trying to build a android app. I was about to start by creating a simple calculator just to see how it goes and I am stuck on a weird problem. I tried to put several buttons on the design view by drag and drop but the problem is I can't place them freely. For example I have 2 buttons ( button1 using it for number "1" and button2 using it for number "2" ) so **I want to place button2 on the RIGHT of button1 but I cannot**. The only place I can place it is below of button1 , its like my app is created only for horizontal alignment .

I tried changing the layouts , margins and paddings but I still couldn't find the solution.

(first time posting sorry about mistakes)

Comment: What kind of layout are you using? If it's a `LinearLayout`, have you tried changing [its orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation)?

Comment: Yes is LinearLayout, but changing its orientation to horizontal it will be the same result but horizontally...What i actually want to do is to create 9 x 9 button "menu" ... Just think about the buttons of a real calculator.. Starting from 1 ending up to 9.

Comment: Then perhaps you should be using [a `GridLayout`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gridlayout/).

Comment: Using GridLayout has the exact same result . Obviously am missing something like an option change but i can't find it.